# delta function on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a well known formula for delta function in complex plane
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}=-2\pi \delta^{(2)}(z)
\end{equation}

I am wondering the following computation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}=2\frac{1}{\bar{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}=-4\pi\frac{1}{\bar{z}} \delta^{(2)}(z)=-4\pi\frac{1}{0} \delta^{(2)}(z)
\end{equation}
is right or not? If the this is right, then the quantity $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}^2}$ seems not well defined.

Comment: Can you define $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ and $ \delta^{(2)}(z)$ in term of integration wrt $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{C})$.

Answer (score 1):

- For $f(z)=f(x+iy) \in C^1(\Bbb{R}^2)=C^1(\Bbb{C})$ the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) is

  $$\partial_z f=\frac12(\partial_x f-i\partial_y f),\qquad \partial_{\overline{z}} f=\frac12(\partial_x f+i\partial_y f)$$

  Let
  $$g(z) = \frac1{x-iy} \in L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R}^2)=L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{C})$$
  That it is locally integrable means it defines a distribution $$<g,\phi>\ =\ \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} g(x+iy)\phi(x+iy)dxdy, \qquad \phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{C})$$

  The distribution $\partial_z g$ is defined as
  $$<\partial_zg,\phi>\ =\ <g,\partial_z \phi>$$

  $g$ is $C^1(\Bbb{C}^*)$ and for $z \ne 0$, $\partial_z g(z)= -\frac1{\overline{z}^2}\partial_z \overline{z} = 0$.

  From this and $<g, e^{-|z|^2}>\ =\ <g, z e^{-|z|^2}>\ = 0$ we obtain $$<\partial_z g,\phi>=-2\pi \partial_z\partial_{\overline{z}} \phi(0)$$
- $$g(z)^2 \not \in L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{C})$$ Thus $\phi \ \mapsto\ <g^2,\phi>$ doesn't define a distribution and it is perfectly normal that you find $\phi\ \mapsto\ <\partial_z g^2,\phi>$ is ill-defined too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Are there any procedures to regularized this divergence at $z=0$ for this function, i. e. isolate the divergent part?